# Spinnaker server group labelling

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am creating a server group and I want to add a label to the deployment. I don't find any option in the spinnaker UI to add one. Any help on this?

Comment: Hi, you can use `kubectl label` command to label the pods. you can get the examples with `kubectl label -h`.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I don't want to edit the deployments created by Spinnaker. Is there a way to add labels while creating the deployment?

Comment: Hi, You can add your own label or overwrite after deployment of the spinnaker with the above command.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Do you mean to say there's no way to add labels on the fly while creating the deployment? FYI - Spinnaker adds few info as labels while creating the server group, such as version, app, cluster, pod-template-hash etc. I want my custom label to be added during the same time, these above labels are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of the Kubernetes cloud provider (v1) does not support configuring labels on Server Groups.

The new Kubernetes Provider (v2), which is manifest-based, allows you to configure labels. This version, however, is still in alpha.

**Sources**

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1624
https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/providers/kubernetes-v2/